# Custom domains/SSL binding in Microsoft Azure server

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have installed SSL successful in my azure server but it's not binding with domain. I am getting following error message.

[image]

Comment: Do you use self-signed certificate to enable ssl?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I could not have written a more detailed error message myself. Your certificate is missing the required key usage extension. If it's self signed, re-generate with Server Authentication as key usage. If commercial, your certificate signing request (CSR) is missing key usage. `extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth` in OpenSSL lingo.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear on what certificate you are using. To use a certificate in App Service, the certificate must meet all the following requirements:

Signed by a trusted certificate authority
Exported as a password-protected PFX file
Contains private key at least 2048 bits long
Contains all intermediate certificates in the certificate chain

As highlighted by Snobu you may regenerate the certificate (for Self-Signed) with: extendedKeyUsage = critical,codeSigning,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 in the x509_extensions in the file. Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#prerequisites) for the step-step instructions on uploading a certificate.